# Python - parking JSON file and stucked at empty .items()

Tags: python, json, parsing

So I am parsing some JSON file and it always breaks when code gets to one that has empty '' value for .items():

```
for i,n in v['objects'].items():
```

I get:

```
AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Whenever code gets to some item that has field:

```
"objects": ""
```

Does anyone know how to handle this? I tried with checking first if it is empty, but no success.
I tried with this before my FOR:

```
objects_empty = ""
if not v['objects'].items() == objects_empty:
```

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `.items()` from your if-condition, you want to check if `v["objects"]` is an empty string, not if its items is an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the earlier comment]

`v['objects']` is the value that can be an empty string instead of a dictionary. Hence, you want to check whether this value equals the empty string and not its `.items()`. A string doesn't have items, that's what the error message complains about.

You can change it to this:

```py
if v["objects"] != "":
    ...
```